# In various operating systems, why does closing a shell window interrupt code running in that shell?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, shell, unix

It's clear that a keyboard interrupt can stop code executing in a command shell on various operating systems. However, what happens when a window is closed that also causes code to stop executing?

Comment: It might be because stdin/stdout is lost. Also, most terminals will send a signal to child processes when exiting.

Comment: Are you asking what the purpose is, or what the mechanism is?

Comment: Or are you really asking how to start something from the shell that keeps running even after you terminate the shell process? If so, we’d probably want to know a little about what that app is doing, as that might affect how you tackle this. E.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/8653 or writing a daemon or ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I've made edits for clarity

Comment: When you close a window (on windows generally by clicking the `[X]` (close) button or using `Alt + F4` or `File->Exit` in the MainWindow), your window manager will send a signal to the processes running in the window. Generally this signal terminates the process running in the window. (the programmer is free to catch and change the behavior) For normal applications like `cmd.exe` or PowerShell, closing the window terminates the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it may interrupt on not. What actually happens is that a window hosts a *shell* (cmd.exe on Windows, xxsh on Posix systems). And all code executing in the window has that shell as ancestor. On Posix system, when the window closes it sends a SIGHUP signal to its shell which sends it in turn to its children.

So there are two way for a code executing in that window to survive the closure:

- explicitely ignore SIGHUP (there is even a command dedicated to that which is `nohup`)
- have an intermediary process to exit. When this happens, its children are *adopted* by the `init` process (PID 1) and no longer depend from the window and its main shell

Remark: this only makes sense for Unix-like like various Unix systems like the xxxBSD, Linux, or recent versions of MAC OS for which the underlying system is Darwin, a derivative from BSD, but does not apply to Microsoft Windows.